# Custom ExceptionListener picks up 403 & 404, but not 500 errors

Tags: symfony

Exact same problem as unanswered question [Symfony 2.4: Why are 500 errors not caught by kernel.exception listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139117/symfony-2-4-why-are-500-errors-not-caught-by-kernel-exception-listener).

I have implemented a custom exception "handler" which works awesomely for 403 and 404 issues, but 500 errors (which is what I REALLY want to handle, as I want to send an email to myself from the system when this happens) does not trigger my custom "handler" and continues to behave as if the custom "handler" was not there. The code is relatively straight forward:

Extract from app/config/config.yml:

```
services:
    core.exceptlistener:
        class: Pmb\LicensingBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener
        arguments:  ["@service_container", "@router"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException, priority: 200 }
```

Entire \Pmb\LicensingBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace Pmb\LicensingBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class ExceptionListener
{
    private $container;
    private $router;

    function __construct($container, $router) 
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        die("test");
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        $templating = $this->container->get('templating');    

        if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException)
        {

            # If AJAX request, do show not error page.
            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) 
            {
                $response = new Response(json_encode(array('error' => 'Access Denied: Not logged in as administrator')));
            }
            else
            {
                return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login'));
            }

            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
        elseif ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404)
        {
            # If AJAX request, do show not error page.
            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) 
            {
                $response = new Response(json_encode(array('error' => 'Requested route could not be found')));
            }
            else
            {
                $response = new Response($templating->render('PmbLicensingBundle:Exception:error404.html.twig', array(
                    'exception' => $exception
                )));
            }

            $event->setResponse($response);
        }       
        else
        {

            # TODO: Send Email
            # If AJAX request, do not show error page.
            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) $response = new Response(json_encode(array('error' => 'Internal Server Error Encountered. Developer has been notified.')));
            else
            {
                $response = new Response($templating->render('PmbLicensingBundle:Exception:error500.html.twig', array(
                    'exception' => $exception
                )));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I put the `die("test")` in there to verify that the "handler" is not being called at all and that is not just a problem with my if-else logic. As stated before, this works awesomely with any 404 or 403 errors, but 500 errors completely ignores this and behaves in the default manner. I am pretty sure that this has to do with the registering of the listener service, but I cannot find anything that explains how to make it work properly.

**EDIT:** Below are screenshots of errors that are not being handled as expected. I notice on the one (undefined variable) the `die("test");` actually displays at the bottom, but on the ohter (syntax error) it does not display, even though both seems like they are being caught by Symfony2. Further testing showed that `die("test");` showed up, but die(">> .$exception->getStatusCode()." <<"); did not. I am assuming that this is causing a second exception which I am not seeing, just like AccessDeniedException did not have this function call and I had to use `instanceof`, but there are many possible errors that can come up with a 500 error, so how do I distinguish whether the error is one of these?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**FURTHER EDIT:** On the error that did print the "Test" at the bottom, I noticed that when I do `$container->testError();`, I do not get the "Test", at the bottom of the error, but when I do `return $container;`, I do, even though both errors are ContextErrorException with undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 errors you got most probably before Symfony has chance to start. Since Symfony doesn't start in this case it cannot handle errors. To debug such cases, you should look at web server  (apache, ngnix, etc) logs.

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far. As far as I can tell all errors are being caught after Symfony have started, as they are all displayed within the normal Symfony format with the grey background message and debug backtrace. I have added additional test results and screenshots to my original problem description. Perhaps these can help?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested catching 500 exceptions and it seems to work fine.  I think you may have something else intercepting the exception?  Perhaps start a new project and try it again.

I myself prefer the subscriber interface:

```
class ExceptionListener extends ContainerAware implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => array(
            array('doException', 200),
        ));
    }
    public function doException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $doEvent)
    {
        $exception = $doEvent->getException();

        die('Exception caught ' . $exception->getStatusCode());

cerad_core__exception_listener:
    class:   Cerad\Bundle\CoreBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Be aware that you can also configure the logger to send emails.  Might be easier.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html

@Ferhad makes a good point.  Some (but not all) 500 errors will basically crash the S2 app.  But I am assuming that you are getting the default S2 exception message.

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far. I would like to keep it going through the listener, as my Symfony2 knowledge is still in its infancy and I have this working 80% perfectly, except for the 500 errors. I have updated my orignal problem description with additional screenshots and test resutls. Could you please look at this and let me know if you have any further advice? I am not too worried about things like syntax errors. I want this handler to catch errors like undefined variables, trying to loop through empty arrays, method calls on non-objects, etc. You know: weird production issues.

Comment: All I can say is:  good luck.  Since your S2 knowledge is still in it's infancy then it might make more sense to use the tools provided instead of making your own.  But that is up to you.  I'm able to catch undefined variables without a problem.  But syntax errors are almost certainly going to be fatal.  Focus on testing your code before moving it into production.